# Maven dependencies from parallel projects, not modules.

Tags: maven, dependencies

I have following maven projects (note : maven project, not maven modules). I know i will get questions, why not modules, but it has its own story, anyway.

myproj-common (JAR), 
myproj-core (JAR), 
myproj-product1-batch (EAR), 
myproj-product2-batch (EAR)

myproj-core depends on myproj-common, and myproj-product1-batch depends on myproj-core.
If it is modules, i can simply create dependency. It if is standard archive, I can also create dependency and have JAR available in repository, if it is a library JAR, I can ...bla bla bla ...all standard dependency I can fix, I am not sure how to make a jar that is sitting somewhere on the disk, a dependency.

I am not able to get 
C:\Documents and Settings\users\myproj-common\target\myproj-common-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
into following jar, as a dependency
C:\Documents and Settings\users\myproj-core\target\myproj-core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

same problem for the JAR into EARs.

Any idea ? How ...hoping a small, quick and surprising fix, just not visible to me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason why you shouldn't be able to use `mvn install` to install these jars and ears into your local repository. Then, you can just include them as dependencies anywhere you like.

I doubt that you'll be able to cleanly get maven to pull in a jar sitting anywhere on your filesystem other than your local repository.

To clarify, when you do `mvn install` it puts your JAR in the target folder, but it also puts it into your local repository (C:\Documents And Settings\.m2 by default in Windows). After that JAR is installed there, you can include that JAR in other projects as a maven dependency using a "dependencies" block in your pom like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>group-a</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifact-a</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The dependencies mechanism is explained in the [Maven Docs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management).

In addition, you'll need to tell maven to actually package all dependencies in the JAR. You can do that by adding this to your POM. (Also check this question [How can I create an executable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven) for the source of this code block).

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
     <descriptorRefs>
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
      <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: When I run mvn install, it produces JARs into target folders, but I can't get common jar included into core jar. I thought there is a way to get JARs from anywhere on the system, in this case in the target folder of another maven project. Also, when you said install into local repository, i did not get that part, all i have in my loacl repo are JARS they are downloaded after i put in dependency.

Comment: This is my pom content from core <br><br><dependency><br> <groupId>com.myorg.myproj</groupId><br> <artifactId>myproj-common</artifactId><br><br> <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version><br> </dependency>

Comment: @questionaire Please post the error that maven gives you when you try to include that dependency (also, I assume that block is from your core project's pom?). Also, please check your local repository to make sure the common JAR actually got there.

Comment: I do see myproj-common.jar in repository, there is no error when i duild myproj-core, it does produces myproj-core.jar, but without myproj-common.jar.

Comment: yes I noticed you posted some guidelines, thanks a lot, I am still struggling with it.

Comment: @questionaire My bad, I forgot an important part! Check my latest edit :)

Comment: jon, thanks a lot, an struggling to get the plugin working, if you have any working example, would appreciate. thanks a lot for your guidance.